# Sorting an OLE SafeArray of Variants in C++

Tags: arrays, sorting, c++11, variant, safearray

I am sorting an OLE SafeArray of Variants. I chose to use the C++ type `_variant_t` to make things simpler.

The array is created in MS Excel in VBA and I pass its first element to my C/C++ DLL that contains the following code snippets.

Everything works well and I get the correct results I want with a nice boost in sorting speed from the DLL.

However, I am not happy with how much code was required. My question is how can this be streamlined?

It is very common in Excel VBA to work with arrays of Variants where each element can have a different subtype. For example, one element might be a BString pointer and the next might be a Double and the next might be a Currency and the next a Long and the next a Variant error code. In fact, there are many possible types and one SafeArray structure may well hold many different Variant types at once.

When I chose to use the `_variant_t` type in C++ my hope was that when sorted it would result in a sort order that closely matches the sort order that MS Excel produces when sorting data in a worksheet.

Alas, this was not at all the case. So I made a custom comparator function that sorts EXACTLY like Excel does when supplied to `std::sort()` or to `std::stable_sort()`. However, the comparator function is much longer than I would have expected.

And I needed a second version for the Descending sort, because the exact order that Excel sorts in, is rather surprising both for ascending and descending and a simple reverse of the boolean does not come close.

So now I have TWO annoyingly long comparator functions.

Is there a way to do this in a smarter fashion?

Here are my two comparator functions (again, these work perfectly):

```
bool CompareVariantsAscending(const _variant_t lhs, const _variant_t rhs) {

    switch (lhs.vt) {

    case VT_R8: case VT_I4: case VT_DATE: case VT_I2: case VT_R4: case VT_CY: case VT_UI1: case VT_DECIMAL: 
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        default:
            return 0 == VarCmp(&(_variant_t)lhs, &(_variant_t)rhs, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE);
            break;
        case VT_NULL: return false; break;
        case VT_EMPTY: case VT_BSTR: case VT_ERROR: case VT_BOOL: return true; break;
        }

    case VT_BSTR:
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        case VT_BSTR:
            return 0 == VarCmp(&(_variant_t)lhs, &(_variant_t)rhs, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE);
            break;
        case VT_EMPTY: case VT_ERROR: case VT_BOOL: return true; break;
        default: return false; break;
        }

    case VT_BOOL:
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        case VT_EMPTY: case VT_ERROR: return true; break;
        case VT_BOOL: return lhs.boolVal > rhs.boolVal; break;
        default: return false; break;
        }

    case VT_ERROR:
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        default: return false; break;
        case VT_EMPTY:  return true; break;
        }

    case VT_EMPTY:  // always last
        return false; break;

    case VT_NULL:   // always first
        return true; break; 

    default: return false;

    }

}


bool CompareVariantsDescending(const _variant_t lhs, const _variant_t rhs) {

    switch (lhs.vt) {

    case VT_R8: case VT_I4: case VT_DATE: case VT_I2: case VT_R4: case VT_CY: case VT_UI1: case VT_DECIMAL: 
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        default:
            return 0 < VarCmp(&(_variant_t)lhs, &(_variant_t)rhs, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE);
            break;
        case VT_NULL: case VT_BSTR: case VT_BOOL: case VT_ERROR: return false; break;
        case VT_EMPTY: return true; break;
        }

    case VT_BSTR:
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        case VT_BSTR:
            return 0 < VarCmp(&(_variant_t)lhs, &(_variant_t)rhs, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE);
            break;
        case VT_ERROR: case VT_BOOL: case VT_NULL: return false; break;
        default: return true; break;
        }

    case VT_BOOL:
        switch (rhs.vt) {       
        case VT_BOOL: return lhs.boolVal < rhs.boolVal; break;
        case VT_ERROR: case VT_NULL: return false; break;
        default: return true; break;
        }

    case VT_ERROR:
        switch (rhs.vt) {
        default: return true; break;
        case VT_NULL: return false; break;
        case VT_ERROR: return false; break;
        }

    case VT_EMPTY:  // always last
        return false; break;

    case VT_NULL:   // always first
        return true; break; 

    default: return false;

    }

}
```

Please refer to the following table of sample data.

The first column shows the array elements with UNSORTED data.

The second column shows how the data is to be sorted in ascending order.

The third column shows how the data is to be sorted in descending order.

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  Data In Array  | Asc Sort Order  | Desc Sort Order |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| anchorage       | -78.96          | #NAME?          |
| 123             | -1              | #N/A            |
| FALSE           | 0               | #DIV/0!         |
| #NAME?          | 0.60625         | TRUE            |
| 0               | 1               | FALSE           |
| 2/18/2019 11:55 | 99.01           | zimmer          |
| #N/A            | 123             | Major Tom       |
| 99.01           | 4/15/2017       | anchorage       |
|                 | 2/18/2019 11:55 | ABC             |
| #DIV/0!         |                 | 888.87          |
|                 | $%^%$^          | $%^%$^          |
| ABC             | 888.87          |                 |
| -78.96          | ABC             | 2/18/2019 11:55 |
| Major Tom       | anchorage       | 4/15/2017       |
| TRUE            | Major Tom       | 123             |
| 4/15/2017       | zimmer          | 99.01           |
| zimmer          | FALSE           | 1               |
| 1               | TRUE            | 0.60625         |
|                 | #NAME?          | 0               |
| -1              | #N/A            | -1              |
| 0.60625         | #DIV/0!         | -78.96          |
| 888.87          |                 |                 |
| $%^%$^          |                 |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Note that the blank element in the 10th position of the Asc Sort Order is a zero-length VT_BSTR, while the two blank elements at the bottom of the column are VT_EMPTY.

My comparator functions above succeed at producing these exact sort orders. But I would like to know if this can be done more concisely and/or more efficiently.

The comparator functions are currently called like this:

```
   std::stable_sort(Data, Data + Rows, CompareVariantsDescending);
```

Comment: Seems like you could pull some common switch cases out. Null and Error on the rhs seem to always return false in the second function except when lhs is error. You've also collapsed some of the cases and not others that could be collapsed. Other than that, you have a bunch of different cases to handle and you need code to do so.

Comment: You don't need `break` statements after `return` and combine / rewrite some checks (Check: https://ideone.com/6xmuiK). Another thing that you can do is rearrange the `case` statements that you think would have more matches. The code looks fine as-is. However, an MCVE would be great for experimenting if you could add in your question along with populated test data e.g. `std::vector`, etc.

Comment: It seems normal to have a bit of code if you need specific code because of Excel, so I don't see what big improvement you could make, beyond marginal ones. Still, if performance is *very* important, you could: 1) stop using smart wrappers (_variant_t), and pass VARIANTs using pointers (VARIANT is big, 16 or 24 bytes in x64) you'll save a bit of memory and a bit of performance, and 2) replace VarCmp (or reduce its usage) by direct VARIANT's comparison. You'll save a bit of performance (and we don't known interns of VarCmp). But this will make your functions bigger...